# Significato di "avere la lingua di ferro"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel racconto *La novella dell’apprendista esattore* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto questa discussione tra un prete e alcuni paesani sulla faccenda di un suo compaesano che si era asserragliato a casa sua, difendendosi a spari, quando era venuto l'esattore a riscuotere una tassa inevasa:

> – Questa è una faccenda, – riprese, – che dovete sbrigar voi, suoi amici da sempre. Voialtri la dovete sbrigare. Andategli sull’aia in tre o quattro e parlategli tutt’insieme o uno alla volta.
>         Carlino sospirò, ma Umberto tentò ancora. – Lei capisce che quello non è normale, e nessuno di noi ignoranti sa le parole da usare nelle situazioni non normali. Lei certo mi capisce, parroco. 
>         – Ti capisco, ma ti dico che tu fai torto alla tua lingua. Voi la sapete usare la lingua, eccome. **Avete tutti una lingua di ferro**. Aspettate. Questo può essere un buon consiglio. Presentatevi tutti sull’aia ma fate parlare Amedeo. Amedeo è o non è il primissimo amico di Davide?

Non capisco cosa significa "avere una lingua di ferro" in questo brano. Ho cercato alle voci "lingua" e "ferro" di parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato questa espressione. Sapreste spiegarmene il significato?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vuol dire "avete una lingua forte". Si lamentano di avere una proprietà di linguaggio debole e non adatta a discutere con lui, ma il parroco risponde che in realtà la loro padronanza della lingua è "forte come il ferro".